# jQuery plugin not exists in chunk

Tags: jquery, vue.js, webpack

I am building a vue app. It have two chunks, "chunk1" and "chunk2". In chunk1, i imported the admin-lte, bootstrap, vue, vue plugins, etc.

AdminLte provides a built-in plugin called Toasts. It is as jQuery Plugin. When i call $(doument).Toast(...), it shows the toast in my chunk1 code. But if i do it in the chunk2 code, an error occurs: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Toasts is not a function:.

jQuery was configured in webpack.ProvidePlugin. Both chunks has access to jQuery, but only the first can call the Toasts plugin.

```js
  entry: {
    chunk1: [
      './src/chunk1.js'
    ],
    chunk2: [
      './src/chunk2.js'
    ]
  }
...
plugins: [
  ...
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$': 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery',
      'window.$': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
  }),
  ...
]
```

Comment: Are you importing admin-lte in chunk2?

Comment: yes, i'am importing

Comment: That's odd, if you're importing the same dependencies in both chunks then Toast should work in both.